# An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, database, entity-framework

When i delete an item in a listbox, i get the error in the question as shown in the screenshot below:
[image: error]

I do not know where the inner exception is, but i tried try, catch but i got the same error in the question.

Here is all of the code :

```
namespace WpfApplication7
 {
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Edit_Rooms.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Edit_Rooms : Window
{
    public Edit_Rooms()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //initialises entities
    WpfApplication7.AllensCroftEntities1 allensCroftEntities1 = new WpfApplication7.AllensCroftEntities1();
    private Room ObjectIndex;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Load data into Rooms. 
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource roomsViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("roomsViewSource")));
        //runs a query to go the roomsQuery to get the rooms table from the entities
        System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<WpfApplication7.Room> roomsQuery = this.GetRoomsQuery(allensCroftEntities1);
        //used when adding new rooms
        roomsViewSource.Source = roomsQuery.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly);
    }

    private System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Room> GetRoomsQuery(AllensCroftEntities1 allensCroftEntities1)
    {
        System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<WpfApplication7.Room> roomsQuery = allensCroftEntities1.Rooms;
        // Returns an ObjectQuery.
        return roomsQuery;
    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //prevents user trying to delete nothing/unselected row
        if (ObjectIndex == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot delete the blank entry");
        }
        else
        {
                //deletes object from dataset, saves it and outputs a message
                allensCroftEntities1.DeleteObject(ObjectIndex);
                allensCroftEntities1.SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Room Deleted");
        }
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //attempts to save changes
            allensCroftEntities1.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //if unsuccessful, outputs an error message
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listbox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //prevents user going to the previous item before the first item
        if (listbox.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            listbox.SelectedIndex -= 1;
        }
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //prevents user going after last item and throwing up an error
        if (listbox.SelectedIndex < listbox.Items.Count)
        {
            listbox.SelectedIndex += 1;
        }
    }

    private void btnLast_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listbox.SelectedIndex = listbox.Items.Count - 1;
    }

    private void listbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //outputs index of the selected room
        ObjectIndex = listbox.SelectedItem as Room;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Click "View Detail..." a window will open where you can expand the "Inner Exception" my guess is that when you try to delete the record there is a reference constraint violation.  The inner exception will give you more information on that so you can modify your code to remove any references prior to deleting the record.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Click "view details" to find the inner exception.