# How to solve System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException in mvc entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a query to update a record in the database. But when I execute it I get an exception saying,

> 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException'

When I view details, it says **"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details"** I have tried many solutions found in the internet. But none of them worked for me.
Here is my code in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult saveChanges(person person1)
{
        person _person = new person();
        _person.SID = person1.SID;
        _person.email = person1.email;
        _person.password = Crypto.HashPassword(person1.password);
        Session["_person"] = _person;

        string sessionValue = Session["userID"].ToString();
        bool status;
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        status = repo.updatePerson(sessionValue,_person);

        return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Code in repository class

```
 public bool updatePerson(string ID,person _objPerson)
 {
      person temp = null;
      temp = (from p in _dbContext.people
                    where p.SID == ID
                    select p).SingleOrDefault();
            temp.FirstName = _objPerson.FirstName;
            temp.LastName = _objPerson.LastName;
            temp.password = _objPerson.password;
            temp.DOB = _objPerson.DOB;
            temp.email = _objPerson.email;
            //_dbContext.SaveChanges();
            //Guid id = _objPerson.Person_ID;
            if (_dbContext.SaveChanges() > 0)
            {
                 return true;
            }
            return false;
```

Comment: _"See the inner exception for details"_ - What does it tell you about the error?

Comment: How do I check the inner exception?

Comment: Debug your code :) - [View detail ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466854/an-error-occurred-while-updating-the-entries-see-the-inner-exception-for-detail)

Comment: I tried using this code.   

string msg = (e.InnerException.Message); It also give the message as "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I could find this message in inner exception "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: One of your person table fields only allows data of a certain length are you passing it a value which is longer than allowed

Comment: @StephenMuecke I removed  Crypto.HashPassword and now its works. Thanks for your help.