# "An Error Occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details." - unable to view "inner exception"

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I am working in ASP.NET MVC5 attempting to make a fairly simple program for a school assignment.

I got this error...
[image: Error Message]

because of this line of code:

```
        context.Facilities.AddOrUpdate(x => x.ID, new Facility() { ID = 1, FacilityAddressId = 1, Name = "School Playground", OwnerId = 1, Indoor = false, Sport = "soccer" });
```

I have now fixed the error. It turns out the foreign key "OwnerId" was referencing an empty table. My question is:

**How could I have viewed the "inner exception" in my error message to help with the debugging process** (the text in the console is plain text, not a link)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466854/an-error-occurred-while-updating-the-entries-see-the-inner-exception-for-detail)

Comment: My exception occurs in the console and my question is how to view the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169020/debug-code-first-entity-framework-migration-codes

Comment: Yes! Thank you, this is exactly what I needed to see!

Comment: Hello Please check Your sql Permissions, and allow your user permissions.